# Background of select in IE left in case of right

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-position

Hi I styled a crossbrowser select, which has the same design on the browsers chrome, IE and safari. I used follow code for this (at the white space on the right side there is for normal the arrow icon):

```css
select{
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid $BORDER_COLOR;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;

  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: radio-container;
  appearance: none;
  background: url("arrow_down_grey.svg") no-repeat center right;
}

select::ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <label>City</label>
  <select>
    <option>Zurich</option>
    <option>Vienna</option>
    <option>Berlin</option>
  </select>
  
  <label>Country</label>
  <select>
    <option>Switzerland</option>
    <option>Austria</option>
    <option>Germany</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

On the browsers chrome and safari (desktop and tablet) it works fine and looks like this:

[image]

But on the IE, the icon is on the left side, not on the right like in the other browsers:

[image]

I found a comment, that IE can't set background positions correctly in select. Is there a good workaround for this? I didn't found anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain in which IE version?

Comment: @Rotan075 Yes, it's IE11..

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have a typo in your CSS:

```
select::ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

Should be:

```
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

You forgot the **-**

Second if I look at this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yvL6vkov/) in IE11 I see the arrow aligned to the right like you wanted. Do you also see that?

Comment: Yes, it's on the right side in the fiddle, but in my website it isn't. I havn't got differences... It's the same code...

Comment: Can you post your website url? So that I can have a look? @MrBuggy

Comment: This isn't possible at this moment... I'll inform you if I found the error.